# Random effects in GAMLSS BEINF family

Tags: r, gamlss

I'm running a GAMLSS in R modelling by random effect. However, this error appears:

> Error in solve.default(pdMatrix(a, factor = TRUE)) :    system is
>   computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 0

I've tried the model without random effect and it worked.

```
mod <- gamlss(proportion ~ categorical_variable + re(random = ~1|subject), family = BEINF(), method = mixed(10, 50), data = na.omit(data1))
```